# Google Script Highlight Text If Variables Differ

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Form and on submission, the spreadsheet runs a script to compare variables and create a new document from a template. I am wanting to also highlight the text in the document when the variables differ in the script. I've figured out that I need to format the text in the document first before I do a replaceText().

```
var matching = e.values[29]; //column in spreadsheet
var keymatching = "2b, 6a, 7a, 8b";

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc to folder, and save Doc's id
var targetFolder = DocsList.getFolderById("0B4bnlgTJUvsgeV9XelN4a243Y1k");
var file = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' ~ '+first_name+' '+last_name);
var copyId = file.getId();
file.addToFolder(targetFolder);

// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document's body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

var background = background || '#F3E2A9';  // default color is light orangish.
var target = 'keyMatching' //text in document
var bodyElement = copyDoc.getBody()
var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target);
var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
var thisElementText = thisElement.asText(); 

if (matching == keymatching) {} else    {thisElementText.setBackgroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset(),searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),background)};

// Replace place holder keys, in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keyMatching', matching);
```

I have 27 targets/key matching variables. Is there a way to loop this so I'm not recreating `var target`, `var seachResult`, `var thisElement` and `var thisElementText` for each of the 27?

Thanks

## Edit:

I have figured out that I most likely need to loop through the variables using an array. Here is my updated code:

```
var matching = e.values[29]; //column in spreadsheet
var keymatching = "2b, 6a, 7a, 8b";

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc to folder, and save Doc's id
var targetFolder = DocsList.getFolderById("0B4bnlgTJUvsgeV9XelN4a243Y1k");
var file = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' ~ '+first_name+' '+last_name);
var copyId = file.getId();
file.addToFolder(targetFolder);

// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document's body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

var background = background || '#F3E2A9';  // default color is light orangish.
var target = ["keyMatching", "keyCount1", "keyCount2"]; //text in document, made an array
var bodyElement = copyDoc.getBody()

for (i in target) {
var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target[i]);
var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
var thisElementText = thisElement.asText(); 

if (matching == keymatching) {} else    {thisElementText.setBackgroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset(),searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),background)};
}  
// Replace place holder keys, in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keyMatching', matching);
```

I'm still stuck on how to get it to only highlight the field in the document when the variables do not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. New code:

```
var matching = e.values[29]; //column in spreadsheet
var keymatching = "2b, 6a, 7a, 8b";

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc to folder, and save Doc's id
var targetFolder = DocsList.getFolderById("0B4bnlgTJUvsgeV9XelN4a243Y1k");
var file = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' ~ '+first_name+' '+last_name);
var copyId = file.getId();
file.addToFolder(targetFolder);

// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document's body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

var background = background || '#F3E2A9';  // default color is light orangish.
var target, targets = ['keyMatching', 'keyCount1', 'keyCount2']; //text in document, made an  array
var bodyElement = copyDoc.getBody()

for (var i=0, iLen=targets.length; i<iLen; i++)
{ target = targets[i]
var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target);
var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
var thisElementText = thisElement.asText(); 

if (target == 'keyMatching')  { 
 if (matching == keymatching) {} else  {thisElementText.setBackgroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset(),searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),background)};
 }
  if (target == 'keyCount1') {
   if (count1 == keycount1) {} else {thisElementText.setBackgroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset(),searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),background)};
  }
   if (target == 'keyCount2') {
    if (count2 == keycount2) {} else {thisElementText.setBackgroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset(),searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),background)};
    } 
}
// Replace place holder keys, in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keyMatching', matching);
```

Thanks